# join and where clause on child in Laravel 5 Eloquent

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5, join

I am developing an application with Laravel 5, I have 2 tables `product` and `Category`, the `product`table has a column `category_id` which refers to `id` of `catgeory` table

I also have 2 models `Category` and `Product`

**Question:**
I just need to add a simple function to my `Category` model which return the categories joined by products where the `product.sx_code = 0` with eloquent

Answer (score 1):

You can just add a normal relationship method and append a `where` condition:

```php
public function specialProducts(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Product')->where('sx_code', 0);
}
```

Comment: @JadJoubran Then you couldn't really put it in the relationship declaration. You'd have to apply it when querying: `$category->specialProducts()->where('sx_code', $code)->get()`

Comment: okay but in my case I need to specify the column name..
I'm trying `->where('table.sx_code', $code)->get();`

Comment: Here in the comments isn't the optimal place to help you with this. Please ask a new question providing all necessary details.